# issues with multiple identities and git and azure devops

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've created a repository in azure devops.
Cloned it locally via visual studio.
Made some changes.
and tried to push them back to azure.
If I do this in visual studio, it works, though i notice that it forces me to choose an identity (i.e. a microsoft account,I have several and I think its the root cause of my problems).

If I push from the git command line, it prompts me for a password...I HAVE worked out that if i embed the username password (which I get from the azure repository page) and embed it in the origin url it will then work...but what a faff.

How does visual studio know my 'identity' but git itself doesnt?
How can I make the git command line (and sourcetree) work without having to hack the origin url and embed username password.

If i clone it direcly on the command line, it wont push, as it takes an identity (from somewhere) that doesnt have writes to push, and I can't seem to work out how to force it to the correct identity.

I'd prefer to not use visual studio to clone, seems wrong...and I can use the username/password url hack, but I'd prefer for it to use my microsoft identities and work seemlessly.

The security seems a bit of a mess.

Comment: Git, on its own, never does any authentication. It fobs that job off on other programs. On Windows, there's a program called Git Credential Manager (that's included with the packaging of WIndows-Git, but not actually part of Git itself), and probably 17 other credential-storage-thingies. It's possible VS has its own credential storage too. I avoid Windows, but this might help you get started: look for the various credential storing programs.

Comment: I'll also note that I prefer ssh, which is ... a lot less fragmented, although even here, there are at least two variants of ssh for Windows, and Git comes with one of them because the old Windows one was inadequate. So even here there are traps. On non-Windows Git systems, there's generally just one ssh and it either works (for all things) or doesn't (for all things), which at least makes testing simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I push from the git command line, it prompts me for a password

It should not (for HTTPS URL), if your `git config --global credential.helper` returns "manager-core" (make sure to use [the latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

But I would clone using my username (the proper Microsoft account name) in the URL

```
git clone https://aUserName@dev.azure.com/aUserName/aProject/_git/aRepo
```

That way, several identities can be cached by the Git credential manager (namely, the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)), in the Windows Credential Manager, with the correct password associated with the correct Microsoft account.

Comment: with a microsoft hat on, my microsoft identity is something like, mark_kooks@hotmail.com.....and because this identity exists in azure, and on my machine it then works it out, I assume the username u r talking about is the azure one?

Comment: the other issue is that when git does prompt for a password, it actually doesnt seem to want to let my type it in!

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd I am talking about the email you are using when working with your Azure repository: if the hotmail one works, use this one.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd Are you in a simple CMD session? What does `git version` and `git config credential.helper` return?